# How to access JSON nested data in flutter dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart

- I have the below json data, wherein I want to access the values inside the `feeling_percentage`.

```
{
    "status": "200",
    "data": {
        "feeling_percentage": {
            "Happy": "0",
            "Sad": "0",
            "Energetic": "0",
            "Calm": "0",
            "Angry": "0",
            "Bored": "0"
        },
    }
}
```

- I am able to fetch it using the below API code

```
Future<List<Data>> makePostRequest() async {
  List<Data> list = [];
  final uri = Uri.parse('<api>');
  final headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Api-Key':'<api_key>'};
  Map<String, dynamic> body = {'user_id': 3206161992, 'feeling_date': '15-04-2022'};
  String jsonBody = json.encode(body);
  final encoding = Encoding.getByName('utf-8');

  Response response = await post(
    uri,
    headers: headers,
    body: jsonBody,
    encoding: encoding,
  );

  int statusCode = response.statusCode;
  String responseBody = response.body;
  print('response body'+ responseBody);
}
```

- After reading few articles, still not able to figure out how do I access the percentage of happy, sad inside the feeling_percentage.
- I have created the model as

```
class Data{
  FeelingPercentage feelingPercentage;

  Data(
      {required this.feelingPercentage});

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Data(
        feelingPercentage: FeelingPercentage.fromJson(json["data"]),
        );
  }
}

class FeelingPercentage {
  String? happy;
  String? sad;
  String? energetic;
  String? calm;
  String? angry;
  String? bored;

  FeelingPercentage({this.happy, this.sad, this.energetic, this.calm, this.angry, this.bored});

  factory FeelingPercentage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return FeelingPercentage(
      happy: json["happy"] as String,
      sad: json["sad"] as String,
      energetic: json["energetic"] as String,
      calm: json["calm"] as String,
      angry: json["angry"] as String,
      bored: json["bored"] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you're not accessing the 'feeling_percentage' key at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

```dart
import 'package:fast_json/fast_json_selector.dart' as parser;

void main() {
  final path = '{}.data.{}.feeling_percentage';
  final level = path.split('.').length;
  void select(parser.JsonSelectorEvent event) {
    final levels = event.levels;
    if (levels.length == level && levels.join('.') == path) {
      print(event.lastValue);
      event.lastValue = null;
    }
  }

  parser.parse(_source, select: select);
}

const _source = '''
{
    "status": "200",
    "data": {
        "feeling_percentage": {
            "Happy": "0",
            "Sad": "0",
            "Energetic": "0",
            "Calm": "0",
            "Angry": "0",
            "Bored": "0"
        }
    }
}''';
```

Output:

```
{Happy: 0, Sad: 0, Energetic: 0, Calm: 0, Angry: 0, Bored: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) website to convert your JSON object to a dart class.
it automatically creates the fromJson function, which can be used to pass JSON and receive the Dart objects.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in your model `feelingPercentage: FeelingPercentage.fromJson(json["data"]),` to `feelingPercentage: FeelingPercentage.fromJson(json["data"]["feeling_percentage"]),`

This will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a JSON decode that will will result in a map, and then do the assigned like you are doing on your `from Json` factory, but as another constructor instead:

Class

```
Todo.fromMap(Map map) :
    this.title = map['title'],
    this.completed = map['completed'];
```

In use

```
Todo.fromMap(json.decode(item))
```

Comment: after using ```json.decode()``` i am getting error as ```Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String')``` but ```response.body()``` is printing the data

Comment: It seems like one of the values you are getting from your json and trying to convert into your object may be null. You may have to review your data and do validations for nulls.

Answer (score 0):

First decode `response.body`, then create `FeelingPercentage` object from `json["data"]["feeling_percentage"]` map.

```
Future<FeelingPercentage> makePostRequest() async {
...
  final json = json.decode(response.body);
  return FeelingPercentage.fromJson(json["data"]["feeling_percentage"])
}

class FeelingPercentage {
  String? happy;
  String? sad;
  String? energetic;
  String? calm;
  String? angry;
  String? bored;

  FeelingPercentage({this.happy, this.sad, this.energetic, this.calm, this.angry, this.bored});

  factory FeelingPercentage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return FeelingPercentage(
      happy: json["Happy"] as String,
      sad: json["Sad"] as String,
      energetic: json["Energetic"] as String,
      calm: json["Calm"] as String,
      angry: json["Angry"] as String,
      bored: json["Bored"] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Error at ```happy: json["happy"] as String,``` as ```_CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)```

Comment: JSON field names seem to have the first letter as capital: "Happy" instead of "happy".